# VBA - Convert Column Values Into Negative

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to convert an entire *Column H* in sheet *Data_TC* from positive values to negative values. The range consists of `H1:LastRow`

I have `LastRow` as a module as follows,

```
Option Explicit

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And here is the code I am working with to convert the values:

```
Worksheets("Data_TC").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Each cell In Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC")))
  If cell.Value > 0 Then
    cell.Value = cell.Value * -1
  End If
Next cell
```

When I run it will convert random values into negative values but that is about it. Any idea why?

Comment: Voting to close as typo, your range is only defined by a single cell :) `Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC"))` should be `Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H1:H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC"))` -- if this is truly doing "random", then you should provide some example inputs and outputs so that we can (hopefully) reproduce the problem you describe in your post :)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
For Each myCell In Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H1:H" & Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If myCell.Value > 0 Then
        myCell.Value = myCell.Value * -1
    End If
Next myCell
```

This will loop through all the cells in column `H` and convert positive numbers to negative

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a *range* of cells. What you're doing is check only the last cell with value.
 Try changing:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC")))
```

to:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H1:H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on my test, you could try the VBA code as below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub convertValue()
Dim cell As Range
Worksheets("Data_TC").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
For Each cell In Sheets("Data_TC").Range("H1:H" & LastRow(Sheets("Data_TC")))
  If cell.Value > 0 Then
    cell.Value = cell.Value * -1
  End If
Next cell
End Sub
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Hopefully it helps you.